# What is a reasonable range of penalty values to try in PELT changepoint analysis?

Tags: r, change-point

I have a simulated a time series data set several predictor variables and response class that I created to practice different analytical techniques before I apply methods to my real (very large) dataset and I'd like to use change point analysis to identify the segments of the data that are consistent and therefore likely consist of the individual behavioral bouts.

While my question is ultimately theoretical in nature, it may be helpful to know that I'm using the **changepoint** library in program R and that I am using **PELT** with a range of penalty values (CROPS) to help me determine the optimal penalty values and thus number of change points in my dataset. However, I am confused as to **what exactly these penalty values are** and therefore **how to choose an optimal "range"** of penalty values to use.

I found these two stackexchange posts that also ask similar questions but I don't see a firm answer onto what exactly the penalty value is [post1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60245/penalty-value-in-changepoint-analysis) and [post2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472817/changepoint-pelt-penalty).

Confusing the matter a little bit, is that I think the values of the penalty values (pen.values in the cpt fcn) seem to change based on the method being considered.
Like for binary segmentation the *pen.value* can take on a range from 0 to 1, and similarly an asymptotic penalty (which maybe is only available for the AMOC method?), the *pen.value* attributes is the theoretical type I error.
In other places I've seen it specified that the *pen.value* takes on a value of 0, or "2*log(n)" or the length of the data. This makes me think that the penalty value should be, at least in some way, related to the length of the dataset. Or maybe the expected number of breakpoints in the dataset?

My dataset is 15,900 observations long composed of 1590 seconds of behavior (sampled at a 10 Hz frequency). I've tried running a large combination of penalty values just to see how it affects the data set as well as varying the penalty type used to estimate the segments but all vastly overestimate the number of change points in my data set which makes me wonder if the penalties (like 0, 2*log(n), (# of seconds), or even n) is somehow unrealistic for my dataset?

**Can someone please explain what the penalty values are?** And if these is any "rule of thumb" type metric that I can use to help me figure out a decent range to consider?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the penalty value for PELT?*

PELT segments the data $y_{1:n} = (y_1, \dots, y_n)$ with change points $(\tau_0, \tau_1, \dots, \tau_{m+1})$ (where $\tau_0 = 0, \tau_{m+1} = n$) to make segments $y_{(\tau_0 + 1):\tau_1}, y_{(\tau_1 + 1):\tau_2}, \dots, y_{(\tau_m + 1):\tau_{m+1}}$. In the [paper where PELT is described](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1438.pdf), it says that it chooses the segmentation to minimise the function
$$\beta m + \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}C\left(y_{(\tau_i + 1):\tau_{i+1}}\right),$$
so $\beta$ is a penalty term for each change that we add, in order that we won't just put too many changes, and $C$ is a cost function (the default $C$ is twice the negative normal log-likelihood).

If you choose $\beta = 2\log(n)$ then you are asking PELT to choose the change points to minimise the [Bayesian Information Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) (BIC) for a model with 1 parameter fit per segment. Each change point adds two parameters to the model (1 for the segment parameter and 1 for the new change point). As you get lots of data, the BIC is likely to be lowest for the correct model, it's a heuristic to balance the good fit of model complexity with a penalty for complicated models.

*How to choose an optimal range?*

It really depends on your application and what cost function you're using. Without seeing the data and PELT's proposed change points it's hard to say whether the change points are over/underfitting to the data. In general the BIC is a good starting point but it generally chooses too many change points. Having the penalty as a function of $\log(n)$ will help to keep the number of change points in check. I would just experiment with different penalty values on the type of data that you're using. If you wanted a scheme of penalties to try you could start with $2\log(n)$ and then keep doubling it until the change points fit for the application you have in mind. In my answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/617116/detecting-events-in-a-series) I just experimented with larger penalties until it was only selecting the larger mean shifts in the data.